# INSTR to implement LIKE operator in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to create a measure where I sum a quantity field where a certain attribute member contains "%-ABS"

With some searches I think I have to use the Instr function in MDX but clearly i'm doing something wrong because I get a null value which isn't correct.

Here is the code in SQL

```sql
WHERE [Job No_] like '%-ABS'
```

Here is my current MDX statement

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Ledger Entry - Absences]
 AS Sum({InStr([Fact Operational Job Ledger Entries Fields].[Job No].allmembers, "-ABS")},[Measures].[Quantity - Actuals]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#.00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Test Measures'  ;
```

I expect the output not to be null , because I have data across multiple years and we have entries which have this Job No.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the example below. This would explain how to use instr to implement like in MDX

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
FILTER([Product].[Category].[Category],
Instr([Product].[Category].currentmember.name, 'Bik') > 0
or 
Instr([Product].[Category].currentmember.name, 'oth') > 0
)
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Comment: That is close but the LIKE '%-ABS' ensures that it matches the end of the string. How about: `FILTER([Fact Operational Job Ledger Entries Fields].[Job No].allmembers, Right([Fact Operational Job Ledger Entries Fields].[Job No].CurrentMember.Name, 4) = "-ABS")`

Comment: @GregGalloway you are correct, the query above will find the string irrespective of position. Where as the change you suggested will find it at the end of the string.

Comment: @KevinP did the above help?